# Testing Parent Component's Prop Function in React w/ Jest & Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to test-drive my learning of React development, making a todo list app; it has a `TodoList` component (parent) and `Todo` component (child).

All my tests are passing green but one: I'm trying to test a delete handler that is passed down to `Todo` children as a prop function.

I have a passing test for the Todo-side; it calls the delete handler prop function. But when it comes to the parent, it deletes from the state/list, but I'm having trouble writing a stumble test.

The `TodoList` parent component has a `deleteHandler` function which takes an id and handles the actual deletion form state without issue.

TodoList:

```js
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      task: '',
      items: [],
      lastUsedId: 1
    }
  }

  handleDelete = index => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      items: this.state.items.filter((item, idx) => idx !== index)
    })
  }
```

TodoList.test.js:

```js
describe('when deleting an existing item', () => {

    const todoList = mount(<TodoList />)

    const newItem = 'Sell my Xbox One'
    todoList.find('#new-item-title').simulate('change', { target : { value: newItem } })
    todoList.find('#btn-add-item').simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} })

    todoList.find('.btn-delete-item').simulate('click')

    it('is delete from the state', () => {
      expect(todoList.state('items')).toEqual([])
    })

    it('is deleted from the page', () => {
      expect(todoList.children().find('li').exists()).toBe(false)
    })
  })
```

Comment: Not all of that code is actually inside of your test... Also don't test the `state` directly; that's implementation, test the *behaviour*. In this case maybe counting the number of `Todo`s that get rendered is zero.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for that. I've left out the describe block to keep this question as short as possible. There is another expectation in that block that tests the number rendered, but without being able to get back the result of the prop function, the simulated click is useless...

Comment: A [mcve] needs to let other people recreate the issue, but you shouldn't just have it floating around the describe block either.